# Java JPane Option Window Problems

Tags: java

This last program we did, stupid simple, was to just use a jpane and graphics to draw 3 non primative shapes but I need a way so that a message (JOptionPane) shows up AFTER the JPane is closed> if you have it after in the code, they both go at the same time

Answer (score 0):

What is a jpane/JPane?  Neither are J2SE classes.

In either case, if you drop the 3 shapes into a JPanel (or any other non top-level container that will take them) and display that in a JOptionPane, the 2nd JOptionPane will not appear until the 1st is dismissed/canceled.

Answer (score 0):

add a WindowListener to the Window in which the JPanel is. Put the JOptionPane code in the windowClosing method (manually dispose the parent window before you show the JOptionPane), or try it in the windowClosed method (i usually don't use it because often this terminate the program)